# rsync freebsd client, rsync linux server

Tags: linux, freebsd, rsync

Many hours to check this script but nothing of good...
I've a linux rsync server and with linux client I use:

```
rsync --password-file=/usr/home/user/.rsync.pass --log-file=/var/log/docs.log --progress --stats -avr --delete user@10.10.10.8::docs /home/user/docs
```

everything ok, the problem is with FreeBSD rsync client:

```
msg checking charset: ASCII
rsync: safe_read failed to read 1 bytes [Receiver]: Connection reset by peer (54)
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=251): entered
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(251) [Receiver=3.1.0]
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=251): about to call exit(12)
```

ssh port on linux server is 10321

also using

```
--rsh='ssh -p10321'
```

I've same problem :-(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using following command in FreeBSD to get data through SSH tunnel:

```
rsync -auv -e 'ssh -i /home/id_rsa -p 12345' user@host:~/path/*.gz ../
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I solved changed tap to tun in openvpn server (I think was a bridge problem of that client, but I was enough time to investigate... for now). But thanks :-)